# how can I show a texture over my bump texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, node-editor

So I've got a bump node setup using one black and white texture.
but now I need to show my blue texture over my bump texture.
How do I do this?

[image: trying to combine bump with texture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node setup you have shown looks like it should work fine.  I believe your problem is that you are multiplying the bump map by `0.000`, effectively disabling it.  Try increasing the value of the Multiply node.

If the Multiply node is just supposed to control the strength, you don't need it at all, you can just adjust the *Strength* slider on the Bump Map node.  You can also delete the *Invert* Color node and use the *Invert* checkbox on the Bump Map node.

Just select the Invert node and the Math Multiply node and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to delete them and keep the other nodes connected.  Then adjust the Strength and select Invert on the Bump Map node itself.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try plugging the bump map into the displacement input of the material output.